# File wp-db.php is deprecated since version 6.1.0! Use wp-includes/class-wpdb.php instead

Tags: php, wordpress

After an automatic update to my WordPress installation, my website is display this error rather than loading.

```
Deprecated: File wp-db.php is deprecated since version 6.1.0! Use wp-includes/class-wpdb.php instead. in /home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5595

Warning: require(/home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-dependencies.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 23

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-dependencies.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 23

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835
There has been a critical error on this website.
```

Can someone help me understand this error, and provide me a solution or some hints so that I can figure a fix for this.

Comment: You were using WordPress version less then 6.1.0. in your theme some where the file "wp-db.php" is called but after version 6.1.0 it is no longer supported by WordPress. Go to you web cPanel and change the THEME to WordPress default. The file requested at {/home/vol13_4/epizy.com/epiz_30367402/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 23} is missing too.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem currently. So here's how I fixed it.
Go to your Website's App Installer > Wordpress > and find something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhm0.png

Click the one in the blue box i drew at the right (Wordpress Manager)
Then, there you can update wordpress

Hope it helped!

Comment: It helped but it doesn't probably work.

Comment: Did you try doing it? You won't lose anything trying it. I've tried it and it worked for me!
I've researched multiple fixes but it just caused more errors. So I needed to think of a solution myself. Then this is what i've thought, and it worked!

Comment: @Haris My problem was                   file wp-db.php is deprecated since version 6.1.0! use wp-includes/class-wpdb.php instead. in /home/vol1000_7/unaux.com/unaux_32781661/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5593

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I wanted to write 'properly' and mistyped it to 'probably'. It fixed the problem but then the same happened after a few minutes. The final solution was to disable auto updates in WordPress. @princess-lxz

Comment: Ohh alright, np

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. One of my PHP files included the old file, like so:

`include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';`

I now replaced the above line with the following line:

`include_once $path . '/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php';`

I saved the file and refreshed it and it started to work correctly without any issues.

In order to solve your issue, simply search for all occurrences of `wp-db.php` and replace it with `class-wpdb.php` in all your scripts and you should be good to go!

Answer (score -1):

i solved it just by updating all plugins, idk why it worked but you can give it a try.